# node js express js request response circle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am curious and really willing to learn and understand the whole concept behind the request and response circle of all backend

my question is I have a node js express framework

app is started

````
app.use('/api',router)


require('./routers/user')(router)
require('./routers/uretim')(router)
require('./routers/durus')(router)
require('./routers/rapor')(router)```
````

all my functions are called and executed and waiting for a request

since the order of this app is first use
`app.use('/api',router)`

then the router is called at this particular point router function has nothing attached to it,

so does it mean as we started our application we have created the routes with the executed functions below the app.use

main question

user enter ..../api

our back end was hit

what is the first process, or function that happens within our backend?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but whatever controller logic you have at for the route `/api` will be hit.. what is `router` ? The documentation is pretty clear around this.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes

Comment: Alright i just wanted to know how the routes where created since those are just functions being called, so my question was the route was ready and waiting already created as my app was started

Comment: Ah okay.. well actually, those routes shouldnt be accessible because you havent actually defined them.. You're only using the router middleware (not sure you need to do this), but you would need to define the route. ie: `app.get('/sub_api', (res, req) => { res.send('ok') };)` this would define a GET on that route..

Answer (score 1):

So the [USE](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) is used to load middleware, what you have is to use the `router` middleware on the `/get` url..

A better example of what is happening here is to define some action middleware on that url :

```
app.use("/api", (req, res, next) => {
    // For example, a GET request to `/api` will print "GET /api"
    console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  
    next();
  });
```

When you start your server, if you hit your /api url, it will log the request info in the console and continue.

However the other URL's will not.. So you can tailor specific middleware for certain endpoints.

As for your routing itself, you will need to define the routes and their controller logic. Something like :

```
// HTTP GET Request Definition
app.get('/api',(req, res) => {
    res.send("Hey, you hit API");
} );
```

This will happen after the middleware has been actioned.

[Express](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes)

Comment: well explained thank you.